# "Не заперев" или "не заперши" — как правильно?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Ушёл не заперев дверь или ушёл не заперши дверь?

Answer (score 2):

Д. Розенталь в §177. Формы деепричастий, пункт 2 употребление деепричастий заперев - заперши объясняет так: "Варианты деепричастий заперши, умерши, отперши, вытерши, натерши при наличии нормативных заперев, умерев, отперев, вытерев, натерев являются допустимыми". При этом деепричастия вместе с зависимыми словами, т. е. деепричастные обороты "не заперев дверь\не заперши дверь" выделяются запятыми.

Answer (score 1):

Ушёл, не заперев дверь. Не забывайте про запятые, деепричастные обороты требуют обособления.

Что касается форм на -ши, то в большинстве своём они устаревшие. При этом даже такая устаревшая форма к "запереть" будет "заперевши". Иногда встречающиеся формы без "-ев-"/"-в-"  типа "зеперши", "умерши", "вытерши" - просторечия.

ЗЫ увидел предыдущий ответ уже после того, как написал свой. Различия можно углядеть в оценке форм как просторечных или допустимых. Не думаю, что это принципиально, но если вдруг, формы типа "умерши" и "заперши" в массе отсутствуют в орфоэпических словарях, отсюда и моя оценка. Хотя сейчас посмотрел - у Аванесова зАперши (м умЕрши) тоже признаются допустимыми.